# ARRAY function in SAS after MEAN (by grouping)

Tags: arrays, sas, mean

There is some homework for SAS and I just can't seem to find the right way to do it. Hopefully, some of you will be able to help.

We start with a table where we have the following variables:

```
City     State     Temp January     Temp Feb     Temp Mar    ...    Temp Dec
```

First, we have to calculate the mean temperature (per month, so for 12 different variables) and per state (so there are always a few cities per state).

I used this code:

```
PROC SORT DATA=Homework;
BY state;
RUN;
PROC MEANS DATA=Homework;   
    VAR JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC;
    BY State
    OUTPUT OUT=MTSM (DROP=_type_ _freq_) MEAN=;
    RUN;
```

My result is a table in which I have 53 rows (one per state) and 1 column per month (and a first column for the states of cours). Something like this:

```
State     JAN       FEB     ...     DEC
State1    xjan      xfeb    ...     xdec
State2                   
...                   
State53
```

Now I need to use an `Array statement` to make a new table in long format:

```
State     Month      Mean_temp
State1    JAN        xjan
state1    FEB        xfeb
.         MAR        ...
.         APR        ...
.         ...        ... 
State1    DEC        xdec
State 2   JAN        ...
          ...
          DEC
...
State53   JAN
          FEB
          ...
```

Does someone have an idea of how to do this? I'm completely lost.
This is what I tried:

```
DATA MTSM2;
    SET MTSM;
    BY state;
    ARRAY newvars {1} Mean_Temp;
    ARRAY oldvars {1, 12} JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC;
    DO Month = JAN to DEC;
    DO k=1;
        newvars{k} = oldvars{k, Month};
    END;
    OUTPUT;
    END;
    KEEP state Month Mean_Temp;
RUN;
```

I got following error: `ERROR: Array subscript out of range at line 30 column 22` :'(

What am I doing wrong? I have been changing this in many ways, but always get the same error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think you need to use an ARRAY?

Comment: Run this example. It shows different ways to summarize your data and how you can use PROC MEANS to get what you want directly - no extra step needed.

Comment: @Tom: It's not that I think I need to use it, it is part of the assignment. But I also just discovered I didn't understand the question right and changed it here as well. I also added the code I tried to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close.

There is no need to use ARRAY for the new variable since it is just one. There is no need to tell SAS how many variables there are in the array when you have listed the actual variable names. And arrays are indexed by integers, not strings. You can use the `VNAME()` function to find the name of the variable addressed by the index into the array.  The BY statement is not needed.

```
DATA MTSM2;
    SET MTSM;
    ARRAY oldvars JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC;
    length month $32 mean_temp 8;
    DO month_number = 1 to 12 ;
        month=vname( oldvars[month_number] );
        mean_temp = oldvars[month_number] ;
        OUTPUT;
    END;
    KEEP state Month Mean_Temp;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the table you want by using a more specific `output` statement in `proc means`/`proc summary`:

```
/*Generate some dummy data*/
data have;
call streaminit(1);
do j = 1 to 10;
  do state = 'a', 'b', 'c';
    array months[12] m1-m12;
    do i = 1 to dim(months);
      months[i] = rand('uniform');
    end;
    output;
  end;
end;
drop i j;
run;

proc summary nway data = have;
 var m1-m12;
 class state;
 output out = want(drop = _TYPE_ _FREQ_) mean=;
run;
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for helping out. I didn't get my assignment question right and changed up the question here in stackoverflow. I'm not sure your current answer will work out for the final table I need. Could you look at the last code I tried (in the question)? And thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If the homework is to pivot the data, using `ARRAY`, from the categorically organized layout (`state`/`month`/`mean`) to a wide layout (`state`/`month-1`...`month-12`) you can use `BY` processing and `index` determination to fill an array.

Essentially for each `BY` group there will be one row output.

One way is to use a DOW loop in which the `SET` statement is inside an explicit loop.

```
data want(keep=state jan--dec);
  do until (last.state);
    set have;
    by state;
    array months jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec;
    index = (index('JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC', trim(month))+2)/3;
    months(index) = mean;
  end;
run;
```

If the data is known to have every month, the index 'lookup' is not needed and can be retrieved directly from the do loop index variable:

```
data want(keep=state jan--dec);
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.state);   /* repurpose _n_ */
    set have;
    by state;
    array months jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec;
    months(_n_) = mean;
  end;
run;
```

**Update**

Using `array` to pivot data from an *across* layout to a *down* layout.  Iterate a loop over the array elements and `output` name/value pairs within the loop.

```
data want (keep=state month percent);
  set have;
  array months jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec;

  do _n_ = 1 to dim(months);
    month = vname(months(_n_));     /* name */
    percent = months(_n_);          /* value */
    OUTPUT;
  end;
run;
```

`Proc TRANSPOSE` can perform the same data transformation.

Array based pivoting is very useful when you want to transpose two or more arrays at the same time.  An example would be if you had variables

- `jan_percent` to `dec_percent` and
- `jan_rating` to `dec_rating`

that you wanted to pivot into a data form of `month`/`percent`/`rating`.  Such a transformation with `TRANSPOSE` requires multiple proc steps (one per array).

Comment: Hey Richard, If I would have understood my assignment question in time, I guess you would have given me the solution I'm searching for. I changed up the question, into what I should have been asking (but did not understand until now). So what I have is state jan--dec and I want to go to state month mean... That's the opposite of what you suggested. But I'm to stupid to figure out how to do the opposite by myself. Care to help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you simply want to use a Class Statement instead of a By Statement?

Comment: Right... By using the Class statement I'm already helped with the 53 tables. Now I have only one. However I still don't know how to go from that new table to the one that is asked using that array statement...